# Lightbox, showing images twice

Tags: javascript, lightbox

newbie here with lightbox, basically we wanted to put navigational arrows when viewing our photos, i used lightbox code online from https://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/ and it worked but the problem is 1. when you click on the thumbnail, it will preview twice, the second one has the navigational arrows which is good (i am not sure if there is another JS conflicting) and 2. when you use the navigational arrows and click next, it doesnt go to the next image. TIA!

page > http://www.petitgrande.com/pages/rooms/aqua/ 
image > https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvhfg.jpg

```html
<div class="properties-amenities">
  <div class="main-title-2">
    <h1><span>外観写真ギャラリー</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="imageGallery">
    <h2>外観</h2>
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="1.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="example-gallery">
          <img src="1.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="2.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="example-gallery">
          <img src="2.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="3.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="example-gallery">
          <img src="3.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="4.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="example-gallery">
          <img src="4.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```